# Swift, iOS - have button move up when clicked to display text field? Then move back?

Tags: ios, swift

I know how to accomplish this in something like sprite kit but with just a normal ViewController I'm a little lost - right now I have my button and my UITextfield set up on my xib file. Right now, when the button is clicked my textfield goes from hidden to not, which is great.

Problem is I need to have my button slide up (as in animate up) to "reveal" the text field when clicked. As in the textfield would be underneath the button. When another button is clicked, I want the button to slide back down to its original position. I don't know how to implement these animations.

Here is an image of what I need:

[image]

So the blue button would trigger the move up when clicked. Then if another button is pressed the blue button moves back to original position over textfield.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Will it always be 4 sections like this, or could there be a variable amount of sections?

Comment: Always 4 -  not variable

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option you can try if you aren't displaying these in a `UITableView`:

1. Setup your .xib with all of the possible views in an 'expanded' state.  Give your views that will be revealed a height constraint (in addition to the others needed to layout the view properly), and then create an outlet for those height constraints in your view controller.  Additionally, store a reference to what you want the expanded height of the view to be in your view controller.
2. In `viewDidLoad` of your view controller you will set those height constraints' `constant` values to 0.  This will cause these views to effectively disappear, and your other views should fill in the gaps they leave behind based on their constraints.
3. When one of your buttons is pressed, you'll update which views should be visible by setting their height constraint to 0 if you want them hidden, or to the value you saved earlier if you want them shown.  After the height has been updated, call

   ```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(howLongTheAnimationLasts) {
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }
   ```

   which should animate the change in height values.

Alternatively, you could try putting your options in a `UITableView` and altering their height using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and reloading the cells when their heights should change.

Comment: Thank you, I tried an alternative method first however.. would you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668784/swift-uitextfield-affecting-button-click-unable-to-enter-text-due-to-animation

Comment: I tried implementing your solution - i have not worked with constraints extensively and the height constraint is affecting both the button and the text field, causing both to disappear. Any other ideas?

Comment: Would you by any chance provide an example of how to alter the height constraints without affecting all the other buttons?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of how you have the constraints setup for the expandable views?  Specifically, the Size Inspector panel in IB which lists the constraints (the tab with the ruler icon).  It could be that due to the way your constraints are set up, when you change the height of one view the others don't know how to resize themselves properly.