# Swift: UITextfield affecting button click? Unable to enter text due to animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am having an odd problem with my UIView animations and a UITextfield - I need to be able to click a button, have the button animate up to reveal a textfield so the user can enter text in the text field, then when the user presses that button again user interaction is disabled on the text field and the button moves back over.

This is what I mean-
[image]

I have accomplished this to an extent by placing the textfield behind the button and disabling it at the start, then when the button is clicked the button animates up to reveal the text field, which becomes enabled:

[image]

Problem is that the button click is being triggered (or possibly just the animation) when the user goes to edit the text field. So when they go to type, the button just moves back down and covers the text field.

This is odd because I have a boolean to set whether the button moves up or down, and I do not think this is being flipped because often the button moves BELOW the textfield, which should never happen.

Here is how I'm doing this:

```
@IBAction func enterText(sender: UIButton) {
        print("time to enter text")

        if !textOpen
        {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.textBtn.center.y -= self.textBtn.bounds.height
        })

        happenedTxt.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.textBtn.center.y += self.textBtn.bounds.height
            })

        happenedTxt.userInteractionEnabled = false    
        }

        textOpen = !textOpen
    }
```

How can I trigger the button move ONLY when the button is pressed? Why is the textfield triggering the animation? Is there some call being made to return the button to its original position?

Comment: What is calling the enterText method? Is that the only code that's moving the button?  If you set a breakpoint in your `enterText` method and start typing in the text field, do you hit the breakpoint? My guess is that something else is calling that method, or you have code elsewhere that is moving the button.

Comment: No, nothing else is calling enterText - I know this because the boolean isn't being flipped. And I don't think the button is animating because its moving way too quickly its just returning to its original position. Why would this be happening?