# Swift: can't place UIButton in SAME position (all devices) as other UIObject programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textfield I created in my xib file that has constraints and so changes size/position in accordance with size of device. I am trying to create another UIButton PROGRAMMATICALLY that is placed OVER the existing textfield no matter where the textfield is on the screen.

I have tried setting the center of the programmatically created UIButton to the center of the existing textfield in hopes that this would give them the same position but it does not. For some reason, the programmatically created button is always way off from where the existing textfield is despite being set to the same center coordinates. Here is where I create my button:

```
let txtBtn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
 txtBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, happenedTxt.bounds.height)
        txtBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        txtBtn.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5, happenedTxt.center.y)
        //txtBtn.center = happenedTxt.center
        txtBtn.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

`happenedText` and `txtBtn` need to be in the exact same position regardless of screen size. I have tried:

```
txtBtn.center = CGPointMake(happenedTxt.center.x, happenedTxt.center.y)
```

and

```
txtBtn.center = happenedTxt.center
```

and then tried altering txtBtn's origins when making the frame. No success. How can I place these objects in the SAME position always?

I do not want to use constraints.

Comment: You don't want to use constraints to solve a trivial problem?

Comment: The reason I'm making the button programmatically is to avoid another problem that constraints have caused. Is this possible without constraints?

Comment: I suppose that you can add the button as a subview of the text field.

Comment: Would I be able to move it off it then?

Comment: Where are you doing this work?

Comment: What do you mean? If you look at my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667218/swift-ios-have-button-move-up-when-clicked-to-display-text-field-then-move-b/37667587#37667587 and the one after you will see what I am trying to do. The constraints when creating the button in a xib make the button snap back to its original position every time i enter in the uitextfield. So now I am trying to create it programmatically WITHOUT constraints to avoid this issue. Adding as subview does not work as it needs to move independently

Comment: Don't expect readers to go through your post history to get the bigger picture of what you're trying to do. Each question should stand on its own.

Comment: I know, Im sorry Im on a deadline and Im desperate. Would you look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667218/swift-ios-have-button-move-up-when-clicked-to-display-text-field-then-move-b/37667587#37667587 and see if you have any suggestions please?